# Thinking about using JaCoCo with Maven and Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jacoco

I am thhinking about using JaCoCo with Maven and Jenkins to see if my programmers has tested a % number of the code.  I added the JaCoCO plugin to maven and I see the reporting getting made but can I tell maven to pass the test if X% was tested?

Comment: Why don't you accept one answer before re-asking it again with a minor variation

Answer (score 1):

Start using Sonar server. http://www.sonarsource.org/ ; http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation ; https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar

Sonar uses JaCoCo.

Once sonar configured in user setting.xml (That your team should share)

```
<!-- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven -->
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <!-- FOR MYSQL -->
        <sonar.jdbc.url>
          jdbc:mysql://sonarserver:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
        </sonar.jdbc.url>
        <sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>
        <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
        <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>

        <!-- optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
        <sonar.host.url>
          http://sonarserver:9000
        </sonar.host.url>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

use `mvn sonar:sonar` to analyze any project.

Running instance of Sonar at https://analysis.apache.org/

There is [Sonar plugins for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+plugin), so later all analysis should be run on Jenkins server.